# Check vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

From these which isn't subspace of $C(a,b)$:

a) $\{f\in C(a,b): \lim_{x\to(a+b)/2} f(x)=0\}$
b) $\{f\in C(a,b): \lim_{x\to (a+b)/2} f(x)=1\}$
c) $\{f\in C(-\infty,+\infty): f(x)=f(-x)\}$
d) all of these

Can anyone explain!

Comment: your latex omg pls

Comment: Here's the deal, explain me your latex, show me your working and I explain the answer.

Comment: a),b),c),d) are option chose correct one

Comment: a),b),c),d) are option chose correct one

Comment: I made the input legible; however, I won't give other than a hint: check carefully b.

Comment: It's hard to provide help because I don't know where you are stuck. Do you know what a subspace is? If so, what's preventing you from checking if these are subspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you know about the axioms of a subspace you have to check? 
 For instance, every subspace of a vector space has to contain the zero vector:
 Concerning (b): $ M :=\{f∈C((a,b)):\lim_{x→(a+b)/2}f(x)=1\}$ cant be a subspace of $C((a,b))$, since the function $f \equiv 0 \notin M$. I gave that as an example. Try the others by checking the axioms: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. $W$ is a subspace of $V$, if all of the following axioms hold:

1. The zero vector is in  $W$.
2. If $u$ and $v$ are elements of $W$, then their sum $u$ + $v$ is an element of
   $W$.
3. If v is an element of W and $\lambda $ is an element from $K$, then
   their product  $\lambda v$ is an element of $W$.

Comment: Thnx egreg, simonsays for ur valuable time

Comment: sure! if you give my post an upvote that would be nice, since I could start to comment other posts. thanks

Comment: Good I saw this post. I always make sure that promising new users can comment asap! +1 from me :)

Comment: thanks alot @Math_QED :)

Comment: I don't know how write ques in proper context is there any other method to write question ?